# Выполнение команд из файла

Tags: bash

Пишу скрипт на bash.
Он открывает файл, в котором построчно хранятся команды bash, которые нужно выполнить.
Допустим, у меня есть переменная, в которую я сохранил строчку

```
ls -l
```

Как заставить её выполниться?

Подождите, я делаю сначала

```
a=\`cat ..\folder\file\`
```

Ну а потом b=`$a` работать отказывается (в файле одна строчка).

Я хочу из файла в массив раскидать комманды, а потом уже по моему усмотрению их выполнять.
В каждой переменной будет одна команда, например, "grep блаблабла", "touch xxx" и т.д.

Comment: Вы лучше напишите **что хотите получить**, т.е. зачем все это делаете. А то тут много непонятного, то у Вас есть обратные кавычки в тексте (который в переменной), то нет. 

Вариантов может быть довольно много. Так что, давайте поконкретней.

А самое простое - исполнить этот файл (как скрипт) чем не годится ?

Comment: @avp как я понимаю, обратные кавычки здесь -- это способ на данном сайте вставить код в текст. В e-mail их видно, на странице -- нет.

Comment: Вот я и не могу понять, **что на самом деле** автор хочет.

Answer (score 2):

eval

```
  a='ls -l'
  eval $a
```

Comment: как вариант: 

    a=`ls -l`

разница только в том что в этом случае команда выполнится до присвоения

Comment: А сначала в вопросе содержимое переменной это был текст в обратных кавычках т.е.

    avp@avp-xub11:~/src/yamsort$ echo $a
    `ls -l`
    avp@avp-xub11:~/src/yamsort$ 

Так, вот. Что-то по простому (без "редактирования" содержимого a tr-ом или sed-ом) не получается.

А c='ls -l' т.е.

    ...$ echo $c
    ...$ ls -l

и просто $c (без eval) работает. Собственно eval нужен только для подстановки внутрь.

Comment: @jmu, принципиальная разница - это содержимое переменной a. В случае a=`ls -` echo $a напечатает состав текущего оглавления, а для a='ls -l' естественно строчку ls -l

Comment: > Так, вот. Что-то по простому (без "редактирования" содержимого a tr-ом или sed-ом) не получается.

Можно-же так сделать:

    a='ls -l'
    echo `$a`

UPD. а, или вы про обратные кавычки в самой переменной имели ввиду?

Comment: @Ilya Pirogov, я говорю о содержимом a, которое равно \`ls -l\` (т.е. в a **текст с обратными кавычками**).

Comment: @avp, понял. Да, конечно-же, так работать не будет. Да и через eval тоже.

Comment: @avp: человек все равно потом выполняет эту команду, посему можно упустить лишнее присваивание. упрощенный вариант неподходит только если требуется какая-то манипуляция непосредственно с самой командой

Answer (score 2):

> я хочу из файла в массив раскидать комманды, а потом уже по моему усмотрению их выполнять

В данном случае, я думаю, проще раскидать команды по переменным:

```
# файл commands

CMD_GREP="grep блаблабла $@"
CMD_TOUCH="touch xxx"
CMD_LS="ls -l"
```

А затем просто "импортировать" их и использовать:

```
source commands

$CMD_GREP test_file
$CMD_LS
```

Comment: А не проще всё это алиасами понаписать и с долларами не мучиться?

Comment: Согласен, можно алиасами.

Comment: source это из csh или tcsh. В sh (bash) это коианда **.** (точка).

Да, проще всего прописать команды (и может быть какие-то переменные) в файле и исполнить его (через \`.') в текущем скрипте, а потом использовать эти (новые) переменные (и/или алиасы).

Comment: @avp, в баше тоже source можно использовать. Равносильно точке

Comment: Точно (проверил), а я и не знал. Спасибо.

Comment: @avp, `.`(точка) - это всего-лишь [алиас для `source`](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internal.html#SOURCEREF).